# How to avoid mysql dead lock?

Tags: mysql, database-deadlocks

I am having an issue where I can't remove records. I keep running into dead lock timeout issue.

I am running a simple query

```
delete from phone_calls where status =0
```

after a while I get this error `Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`

What can I do to solve this? is there some wrong with my query?

note if I add a limit 1000 it works but without limits it runs into a dead lock.

Comment: are you using a transaction?

Comment: what do you mean by transactions?

Comment: It sounds like another concurrent query or transaction has the table (or some rows in the table) locked.

Comment: Generally happens when some other thread is holding a record lock. Transactions assure atomic operations in mysql

Comment: but when i do show processlist I get only the delete process on my list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is not a dead lock. It's a simple lock wait timeout. The error given on dead lock is something like "Deadlock found when trying to get lock".

Second, some other transaction is still running and holding the lock on one or several of the rows in phone_calls with status = 0. If status isn't a index you're effectivly holding a table lock and two querires can't do this a the same time. It probably takes a while to delete all such rows and your job is running too often.

Comment: Thank you for this information. Yes and when I did a limit it executed it. Thanks )